# Partial strike through not working on UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I am trying to strike through a part of string on UILabel but it doesn't seem to work. If I give the range as `NSMakeRange(0, str1.length+str2.length)`
 then it strikes the entire string which I don't want.

```
let str1 = RupeeSymbol + " \(providerFare.fareDetails.computedTotalFare+discount)"
let str2 = RupeeSymbol + " \(providerFare.fareDetails.computedTotalFare)"

let strikedOutString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: str1 + str2)
            strikedOutString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, str1.length))

priceLabel.attributedText = strikedOutString
```

Comment: Have you try to init a NSMutableString for first str and set the strike through attribute then append another as a plain NSAttribute str?

Comment: @MatthewLuiHKyes.. it didn't work either

Comment: What happens with the code you posted? And why have you hardcoded the strikethrough style as `1` instead of using the proper constant provided by the API?

Comment: Hi again. I did a few test, yes, the strike through attribute applies to a range only of text cannot be shown properly on UILabel and UITextField, but work on UITextView. How you can observe this, is use a playground and monitor the attribute string style, try to put it on the label, you will see the attribute string itself is correct when the label doesn't

Comment: I ended up using two labels.